# How to integrate VoltDB with Strongloop

Tags: strongloop, loopbackjs

I am trying to use VoltDB with Loopback in my application. I cannot find a proper way to integrate it since there aren't any suppported connectors. Voltdb has a nodejs library (https://github.com/VoltDB/voltdb-client-nodejs). Any suggestios to use it effectively.

Answer (score 0):

Raymond has answered this here.
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/loopbackjs/Cs6IST-c2gU

We don’t have built-in support for VoltDB. It supports SQL for CRUD operations. But the Node.js driver seems to only allow stored procedures.

There are a few options to integrate with LoopBack.

1. Write custom methods for your model and call the driver directly to interact with VoltDB.
2. Develop a connector for VoltDB that implements the CRUD mappings. You can find source code for mysql, postgresql, mssql, or oracle. See https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-connector-mysql/blob/master/lib/mysql.js.